# How to make Media Library files private?

Tags: images, media-library, privacy

I noticed that I can still browse my media library "attachment page" without being logged in.

In other words, it seems like all you need to do is find one attachment page, and then you can see ALL of that blog's images. Is that the case, or am I mistaken?

Seems like a serious problem, especially if people are adding personal photos to their media library, not realizing the photos are automatically exposed to the Internet without any privacy.

To be clear, even if the filenames are totally random, the attachment page "next" and "previous" links seem to expose all the images.

Maybe there should be some kind of warning, or an option to exclude images from attachment pages, or an option to turn off attachment pages altogether?

I'm not asking this for myself. I'm a teacher and would like to know how people approach this problem. The simple solution is, just don't post any images that shouldn't be public. But maybe your company is launching a new product that isn't announced yet, for example.